# Chart.js Stacked Bar - datasets visibility and ordering

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a stacked chart with 3 datasets: Red, Green, Blue. 
Here is the link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bwcfL58v/

[image: Stacked Bar as Layers]

Let's imagine that these are the layers, which overlay each others:
Red as bottom layer, then Green as middle layer and Blue as top layer.

Take a look at the third day: we don't see the red value, cause it behind the green value (red smaller than green here). So, the question is how to move Green to the bottom layer and Red higher. I need the biggest value to be always at the bottom and the smallest value - at the top, this will allow us to see all the datasets for each day.

All I need is to datasets always be visible and do not hide each others.

```
let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Day 1", "Day 2", "Day 3"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Blueberry',
        data: [25, 30, 40],
        backgroundColor: 'blue',                          
      },
      {
        label: 'Greenberry',
        data: [50, 60, 100],
        backgroundColor: 'green',                          
      },
      {
        label: 'Strawberry',
        data: [100, 120, 50],
        backgroundColor: 'red',                          
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        display: false,
        gridLines: {
          drawOnChartArea: false
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Perform a sort in the data property?

Comment: @UtsavPatel what sorting? there are 3 objects in the datasets property, which influence the order of "layers", their sorting already right (from biggest Red value to smallest Blue). Maybe should be sorting for each day, where we can compare values, smth this direction, but how...